# Creating an specific kind of tuple from a dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

First of all, I'm very new to programming. (this is my second question here in the overflow.)

I've been studying for almost 6 hours. I've read a lot here in stackoverflow and many others python websites. Most of my doubts were gone and now I got one I couldn't really solve.

Look, I have this simple dict:

```
player_dict = {'Alice': Rating(),
           'Bob': Rating(),
           'Carla': Rating(),
           'Daniel': Rating(),
           'Esdras': Rating(),
           'Flavia': Rating(),
           'Glauber': Rating(),
           'Hudson': Rating(),
           'Iara': Rating(),
           'Josiane':Rating()}
```

The rating() method creates a tuple like this

```
trueskill.Rating(mu=25, sigma=8.33333)
```

To update those ratings I'm supposed to use the Rating() object in something like this

```
rating_groups = [(player_dict['Alice'],), (player_dict['Bob'],), (player_dict['Carla'],),
                (player_dict['Daniel'],), [...brevity] ]
```

when I print(rating_groups), the IDLE returns me this:

```
[(trueskill.Rating(mu=25, sigma=8.33333),), (trueskill.Rating(mu=25, sigma=8.33333),), [...brevity]
```

So, here is my problem. This last tuple has this "strange" second comma just next to the right parentheses. I already know it's neccesary for the code I'm executing (cuz of the API). What **I want to know is HOW I can transform the player_dictionary in a tuple like this.** I'm not very sure, but it looks like I'm working with a tuple of tuples.

I already tried this very code here:`player_listTuple = [(v, k) for v, k in player_dict.items()]`
and Idle returned me this

```
[('Alice', trueskill.Rating(mu=25.0, sigma=8.33333)), ('Bob', trueskill.Rating(mu=25.0, sigma=8.33333)),
```

without the comma I was expecting to see.

Thanks for the support <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert `player_dictionary` into a list of tuple you can try the following:

```
[(item,) for item in player_dictionary.values()]
```

Comment: That's it! Simply perfect Remy! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure. I'm happy I could help.

Answer (score 1):

`comma` is used to differentiate between a `tuple` and an `expression` surrounded by `()`

For ex:

```
>>> s = ('hello_world')
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> 
>>> s = ('hello_world',)
>>> type(s)
<type 'tuple'>
```

For more than `1 item`, it is not required to add to add the extra `comma`. See for ex:

```
>>> s = (1, 2)
>>> type(s)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> print(s)
(1, 2)
>>> 
>>> s1 = (1, 2,)
>>> print(s1)
(1, 2)
>>> print(s1)
(1, 2)
```

Let's say you need to add `comma`, you can do something like this,

```
player_listTuple = [(v, k, None) for v, k in player_dict.items()]
```

Comment: JkShaw! Thank you for the answer.

A lot is crystal clear for me.

Anyway, I tried the None before, but I 've found this as an output:

'AttributeError: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sigma''`

Do you know any other way I could solve by not using None?